# How to turn off Requestify JS logging? (throw)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the code: [image]
When I'm starting my js application, it keeps throwing me what the response answer is: [image]

How can i turn it off?

I need to turn off same logging, how could I?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Never used it, but looking at https://github.com/ranm8/requestify/blob/master/lib/requestify.js#L253-L263, it looks like you should be able to do

```
requestify.setLogger({
    error: () => {},
    info: () => {},
    debug: () => {}, 
    warning: () => {}
});
```